# Numpy: given a vector of 0s and 1s, how to efficiently use Numpy functions manipulate values in another array, based on 0/1 value of first array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

So, let us say that we are given an array of `int`s like:

```
x = numpy.array([0, 1, 1, 0])
```

We are also given another array, with `float`s, the same length as `x`:

```
y = numpy.array([-1.5, 2.2, -1.0, 1.0])
```

I want to use `x` and `y` to make an array `z` such that `z[i] = y[i]` if `y[i] <= 0` (regardless of what `x[i]` is), but `z[i] = 0` if `x[i] = 1` AND `y[i] > 0`. So, using our example arrays:

```
z = [-1.5, 0, -1.0, 1.0]
```

This would be easy to do if I were using Python for loops, but **I don't want to use Python `for` loops.** Another idea is to write it using `for` loops, and then simply use something like Cython or Numba to speed up the `for` loop.

However, I want to use Numpy functions as much as possible (that's what makes this question a question), but I don't really see how. Maybe using masks? How would you do it?

Comment: What happens if `x[i] != 0` and `y[i] <= 0`?

Comment: @Carsten I edited my post to make that clear. Basically: `z[i] = y[i]` if `y[i] <= 0` (regardless of what `x[i]` is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method #1: enforce the condition directly.

```
>>> z = y.copy()
>>> z[(x == 1) & (y > 0)] = 0
>>> z
array([-1.5,  0. , -1. ,  1. ])
```

Method #2: use [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
>>> np.where((x == 1) & (y > 0), 0, y)
array([-1.5,  0. , -1. ,  1. ])
```

Comment: Can you run a `timeit` to comment on speed?

Comment: @user89 on my machine with a couple hundred elements, it's a couple orders of magnitude faster than looping

Comment: It should also be `y > 0`, just a minor correction.